# use of uni-directional @OneToMany in odata with jpa leads to an exception

Tags: jpa, odata, olingo

Issue occurs with use of JPA Processor Extension.
If a uni-directional @OneToMany is used the creation of the metamodel fails with following exception

```
No [EntityType] was found for the key class [java.util.Set] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Entity] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>java.util.Set</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element.
```

Example code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALERT")
public class Alert implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4223183779603724128L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private int customerId;

    @Column(name = "PROVIDER")
    private String providerName;
    @Column(name = "ADMIN_MAIL_ID")
    private String adminMailId;
    @Column(name = "WARNING_LIMIT", precision = 16, scale = 3)
    private BigDecimal warningLimit;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "PROVIDER", referencedColumnName = "PROVIDER") })
    private Set<EntityMapping> entities;
  //getters and setters here
```

EntityMapping class code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY_MAPPING")
@IdClass(EntityMappingPK.class)
@Cacheable(false)
public class EntityMapping {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private int customerId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROVIDER")
    private String provider;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY")
    private String entity;
```

Persistence.xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="odataJPAService"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.sample.jpa.model.Alert</class>
        <class>com.sample.jpa.model.EntityMapping</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USR_DUV0WD7DRTHE85J199EC5ZRA1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="u5EMQnwOvtAxoiCQXwIIfmbqS4ICo_Fb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sap://localhost:30415/?currentschema=USR_DUV0WD7DRTHE85J199EC5ZRA1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

odataServiceFactory:

```
public class ServiceFactory extends ODataJPAServiceFactory {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "odataJPAService";

    @Override
    public ODataJPAContext initializeODataJPAContext() throws ODataJPARuntimeException {
        ODataJPAContext oDataJPAContext = getODataJPAContext();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        oDataJPAContext.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        oDataJPAContext.setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        oDataJPAContext.setJPAEdmExtension(new CustomAnnotationProcessor());
        return oDataJPAContext;
    }
```

According to this link, this issue has been resolved:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-526

Comment: Can you paste the complete stacktrace?

Comment: the issue is resolved. I was using an old version of olingo where there was no bug fix.